# Android : How to make an international toast (in different languages)?

Tags: android, toast

I've a simple question : I would like to make an international toast depending on the user's language.

`Toast.makeText(this,"hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

I've created the folders "values" and "values-fr" with the file string.xml
wherein there is respectively :

`<string name="hello">Hello World</string>`

and

`<string name="hello">Bonjour</string>`

Now how to add it in my toast ?
Thank you in advance ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write following.

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.hello), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
getResources().getString(R.string.hello)
```

instead of "hello"

Answer (score 0):

try below code...

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), R.string.hello, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.show();
```